# [0-9]+.txt doesn't seem to be matching text files with numeric names

Tags: php, regex

This pattern doesn't appear to be correctly matching txt files with numeric names: `[0-9]+.txt`. 
Can someone advise me as to what I'm doing wrong?

Context: `$posts = preg_grep("[0-9]+.txt", glob('posts/*.txt'));`

Answer (score 4):

Your expression is missing the delimiters:

```
'~/[0-9]+\.txt$~'
```

But it might just be easier to add this requirement into `glob()` itself:

```
$posts = glob('posts/[0-9]*.txt');
```

Comment: This is for a blog system, and there will probably be more than 10 posts. That's mostly the problem.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser It's only a problem if there could be files starting with a digit followed by letters ... is that a problem? Nevertheless, narrowing it down with `glob()` may still be useful.

Comment: Well, we can never trust the user not to do that, even if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser Sorry, how is the user involved in this? You're not letting them choose their own file names right? :)

Comment: On my current host, the database is actually slower than file access, so yes we're allowing the user to choose their own filename </sad>

Comment: @YetAnotherUser This is not about databases per se, you can pick the file name for the user based on how many files are already present and adding one more.

Comment: I already do that. If we put in a non-numeric filename, it's treated as a "page" and ignored in post views.